# unit test cases getting failed in production only

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am creating unit test cases in Laravel 8 project and everything is working fine in my local. But for other team member they always need to take fresh git repo before running test cases, otherwise some of them will get failed for that member. Actually that testcases should passed, so it is false positive test. How can I fixed it? The testcases should passed on any system.

Team members have already tried to clear cache before running testcases

```php
   php artisan config:clear
   php artisan route:clear
   php artisan view:clear
   composer dump-autoload
```

But the testcases still getting false positive.

My phpunit.xml file configuration

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         cacheResult ="false"
    >
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value="DB_NAME"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
    </phpunit>
```

TestCase.php

```
    <?php
    namespace Tests;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
    use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

    abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
    {
      use CreatesApplication;

      protected function uploads($files) { //my custom function to use in many testcases
        //some coding lines to upload file using actual post route
      }
    }
```

And the testcases may including a custom function(in TestCase.php) or some DB logic. Need help with this.

Comment: Do you have any examples of the failing tests i.e. code, error messages etc.

Comment: no error message, it is just assertGreaterThan(), assertEquals() getting failed like Failed asserting that 0 is greater than 0

Comment: Do they have configured the `.env.testing` correctly ? I am 100% sure they are using some wrong database instead of testing database... Also, are you using `use RefreshDatabase;` trait ?

Comment: we are using only `phpunit.xml` and db configuration is 100% ok in `phpunit.xml`. Yes, I am using `use RefreshDatabase;` @matiaslauriti

Comment: I think the problem is then related to DB. What you mean you have DB logic ? Do you have triggers or stored procedures ? What is the process for getting the project (locally) up ? What do they exactly do to make it work again ?